# Split image array and labels dataframe into train, test and validataion sets

Tags: keras, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, tensor

I have an image array (loaded from a npy file) of shape (30000, 128,128,3) and a labels data frame of shape (30000, 1). How can I split these into training, test and validation sets so that I can proceed to build a CNN Model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the package sklearn. If your imagew array is 'X' and labels is 'Y', use:

```
>> from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

This package split dateset in train,test and validation:

```
>> X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=33)
```

ref : https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

Happy Coding !!